# NVL used within a case statement and a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `WHERE` clause in which a `CASE` statement is used with NVL. Can someone explain the logic used in the below query?

```
SELECT * FROM employee
WHERE
(
    CASE WHEN(employeeid IS NOT NULL
              AND (SELECT 1 FROM optemp a WHERE nvl(a.indicator,'`')= 'Y'))
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END
)=1;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will return a syntax error.  Does it actually work?  I mean, apart from other considerations, the parentheses don't balance.

Comment: fixed it now. could you please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you even need a `CASE` expression here, much less a nested one.  Try this version:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE
    employeeid IS NOT NULL AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM optemp WHERE NVL(indicator, '`')= 'Y')
```

Your original query was using a `CASE` expression which, if the criteria were all present, would generate 1, otherwise it would generate 0.  Then, it checked for a 1 present, but again I don't think that is the best way here.

Comment: thank you, could you explain what this part of the query mean?                           NVL(indicator, '`')= 'Y'

Comment: That just says to replace null `indicator` values with backtick character.  So null would never be true.

Answer (score 0):

The original query is not working in my oracle version 11g.
It is missing an expression in (select 1 from ....), so I added 'exists' to complete the 'when' condition.

The query says; if there is at least 1 record in optemp that has indicator = Y THEN display all employee that has employeid=NULL 2) If no record in optemp that has indicator= Y then display all records in employee table.
NVL function means that if indicator is null, then assign a value of '`'. If indicator is null then this query (select 1 from ...) will be false (` is not equal to Y). Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
select * from employee
where
(case
when(employeeid is not null
and exists(select 1 from optemp a where nvl(a.indicator,'`')= 'Y'))
then 0
else
1
end)=1;
```